# github actions path filtering for mono-repo

Tags: github-actions

What is the right way of setting a path in GH Actions?

pipeline yaml

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'src/msg-receiver'
  workflow_dispatch:
  ...
```

repo structure

```
-
|_ src
|  |_ msg-receiver
|     |_ <dotNet-project-files>
|     |_ ...
|_ readme.md
|_ ...
```

I would like the action to fire every time there is any change into the `msg-receiver` folder, but it never triggers. If I remove the `paths:` then it works

Comment: Did you try using ` src/msg-receiver/**` or `./src/msg-receiver/**`? Moreover, does the workflow need to work for all branch or just for the master branch?

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd!. I think the problem was that GitHub was down... seems to work now :S